# Sending API request through on public ip only

Tags: api, proxy, integration, reverse-proxy, haproxy

We are working on a third party api integration.

Due to security reasons the API hosting company has asked us to give one public ip to whitelist and all the requests will be allowed through this IP only.

But our users are sitting in remote locations with VPN connection so I don’t know how to send the request from one public ip which is available at Head office only.
I have read one thread to achieve this through proxy server on Linux platform. I would really appreciate if someone can provide me steps to do the same in windows platform as I m completely new to proxies and Linux is not available with us at all.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hi Everyone... I would appreciate if someone can sort out my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is to build a service API on top of this 3rd Party API and let your users connect to your Service API instead.
Then you can provide the public IP of your service API to 3rd party to white list and also if in the future they implement extra security feature such as different types of token you need to change in only one place.
However, with this approach, you are responsible for the security of your service API.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was too late to open your answer.